# How to forbid simpl tactic to unfold arithmetic expressions?

Tags: coq

The `simpl` tactic unfolds expressions like `2 + a` to "match trees" which doesn't seem simple at all. For example:

```coq
Goal forall i:Z, ((fun x => x + i) 3 = i + 3).
simpl.
```

Leads to:

```coq
forall i : Z,
match i with
| 0 => 3
| Z.pos y' =>
    Z.pos
      match y' with
      | q~1 =>
          match q with
          | q0~1 => (Pos.succ q0)~1
          | q0~0 => (Pos.succ q0)~0
          | 1 => 3
          end~0
      | q~0 =>
          match q with
          | q0~1 => (Pos.succ q0)~0
          | q0~0 => q0~1
          | 1 => 2
          end~1
      | 1 => 4
      end
| Z.neg y' => Z.pos_sub 3 y'
end = i + 3
```

How to avoid such complications with `simpl` tactic?

This particular goal can be solved with `omega`, but if it is a bit more sophisticated, omega fails, and i have to resort to something like: `replace (2 + a) with (a + 2); simpl; replace (a + 2) with (2 + a)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control definition unfolding with the `Transparent` and `Opaque` commands. In your example, you should be able to say something like

```
Opaque Z.add.
simpl.
Transparent Z.add.
```

Alternatively, the `Arguments` [command](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_command232) can be used to instruct the `simpl` tactic to avoid simplifying terms in certain contexts. E.g.

```
Arguments Z.add _ _ : simpl nomatch.
```

does the trick for me in your case. What this particular variant does is to avoid simplifying a term when a big, ugly `match` would appear in head position after doing so (what you saw in your example). There are other variants too, however.

Finally, just for completeness, the [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr) library provides nice infrastructure for making certain definitions opaque locally. So you could say something like

```
rewrite (lock Z.add) /= -lock.
```

meaning "lock `Z.add`, so that it won't simplify, then simplify the remaining of the expression (the `/=` switch), then unlock the definition again (`-lock`)".

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak how the simpl tactic behaves so you get less matches.

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.

Goal forall i:Z, ((fun x => (x + i)%Z) 3%Z = (i + 3)%Z).
Arguments Z.add x y : simpl nomatch.
simpl.
```

Read more about it [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic135).

Otherwise you can use [other tactics](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/tactic-index.html) that allow you to choose how to reduce. `cbn beta`, for example.